# If / case statement using sql query problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

All,
I am racking my brain trying to figure out the best way to approach this problem that I have.  Essentially I would like to compare two tables and insert a duplicate of an existing record if certain conditions are met - such as if the column called "OrderComplete" is a yes or if the record doesn't currently exist in the insert table.  I was looking to use an IF statement or CASE, but I am stuck with the IF part - Below are the two queries I would like to run, but having a heck of a time writing the IF statement. Any thoughts or ideas?

Both of the queries work well below, but I need a condition that looks for duplicates and only copies if the insert table's item "OrderComplete" is set to yes.  I can put a simple equation, but would like to insert a SELECT or something more complex in the IF area.  And maybe you can't compare two tables within the IF statement, right now just stumped.

```
IF ?????
BEGIN
use [PaperDB]  
INSERT INTO dbo.ORDERED_PARTS_TABLE
       ([OrderPN]
       ,[OldPN]
       ,[OldPN2]
       ,[PartDescription]
       ,[WhereUsed]
       ,[LocationStored]
       ,[LocationDescription]
       ,[AlternateLocationStored]
       ,[AlternateLocationDescription]
       ,[QuantityOnHand]
       ,[ReorderQuantity]
       ,[QuantityToOrder]
       ,[Category]
       ,[LastUpdated]
       ,[spare]
       ,[spare2]
       ,[spare3])
SELECT s.orderpn, s.oldpn, s.oldpn2, s.partdescription, s.whereused, s.locationstored,          
s.locationdescription, s.alternatelocationstored, s.alternatelocationdescription,    
s.quantityonhand, s.reorderquantity, s.reorderquantity - s.QuantityOnHand , s.category,     
s.lastupdated, s.QuantityOnHand , s.ReorderQuantity , s.Spare3 
FROM dbo.PARTS_ORDER_TABLE as s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
ORDERED_PARTS_TABLE as t
on s.OrderPN = t.OrderPN
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            from ORDERED_PARTS_TABLE 
            where s.OrderPN = t.OrderPN)) 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
use [PaperDB]  
INSERT INTO dbo.ORDERED_PARTS_TABLE
([OrderPN]
       ,[OldPN]
       ,[OldPN2]
       ,[PartDescription]
       ,[WhereUsed]
       ,[LocationStored]
       ,[LocationDescription]
       ,[AlternateLocationStored]
       ,[AlternateLocationDescription]
       ,[QuantityOnHand]
       ,[ReorderQuantity]
       ,[QuantityToOrder]
       ,[Category]
       ,[LastUpdated]
       ,[spare]
       ,[spare2]
       ,[spare3])
SELECT s.orderpn, s.oldpn, s.oldpn2, s.partdescription, s.whereused, s.locationstored,   
s.locationdescription, s.alternatelocationstored, s.alternatelocationdescription,  
s.quantityonhand, s.reorderquantity, s.reorderquantity - s.QuantityOnHand , s.category,  
s.lastupdated, s.QuantityOnHand , s.ReorderQuantity , s.Spare3 
FROM dbo.PARTS_ORDER_TABLE as s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
ORDERED_PARTS_TABLE as t
on s.OrderPN = t.OrderPN
WHERE s.OrderPN = t.OrderPN AND t.OrderComplete = 'yes'
END
```

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: For one thing, move the `use` statement before the `if`.  Both of them.

Comment: Could you conform if you're using SQL Server and if so what version?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `MERGE` statement? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx‎

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions - great help.  I will try the Merge command and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand your whole problem but couldn't you use an EXISTS with an IF to accomplish what you need?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.ORDERED_PARTS_TABLE WHERE whatever='??') THEN
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a **MERGE** function.

You can set criteria for matching and perform updates/inserts/deletes as part of a single set based operation.

Pretty good example that you can run here:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/dbms/SQL%20Merge.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to perform a select from both tables.

```
Insert into TableC(
  Col1, 
  Col2
)
Select
  a.Col1,
  a.Col2
From TableA a
join TableB b on b.ID = a.ID
                 --expand this to express the full relationship between the tables.
where a.OrderComplete = 'yes' -- This will give you rows where OrderComplete = Yes
or b.ID is null -- This will add also return results where TableB is missing rows.
```

You will end up with a everything inserted into TableC.